# How to show navbar element only on certain Vue.js components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js app with vue-router in a 3-part component:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <head>
    </head>
    <NavbarComp/>
    <div>
      <div class="middle">
        <router-view/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <FooterComp/>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `<NavbarComp/>` contains a login button, which I'd like to appear only on landing page:

```
<template>
<div>
<nav>
          <router-link to="/" >
          <h3>My Shining app </h3>
          </router-link> 
          <router-link to="/login">
            <button  v-if="section='landing'"> Login</button>              
          </router-link>
</nav>
</div> 
</template>
```

I tried to define a `section` in the store, and define the section as a computed property on each component:

```
  section () {
    this.$store.section = 'login'; 
  }
```

but could not succeed. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: Try doing `v-if="this.$route.name === 'login-route-name'"`

Comment: This works. but actually it should be `v-if="this.$route.name === 'landing'"` . Please asnwer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `v-if` on the button to be:

```
v-if="this.$route.name === 'whatever-your-route-name-is'" // 'landing' according to your comment
```